# MidpointRounding.ToZero doesn't work in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to use different midpoint rounding rules than the default "round to even" `Mathf.Round()` has. `Mathf.Round()` doesn't have parameter for midpoint rounding, so I'm using `System.Math.Round()`.

C# has different strategies for midpoint rounding, specified here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=net-6.0 . `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` and (obviously) `MidpointRounding.ToEven` work in Unity, but others, namely `MidpointRounding.ToZero` don't work, for some reason (*"CS0117: 'MidpointRounding' does not contain a definition for 'ToZero'"*).

```
float firstN = ...
float lastN = ...
int begin = (int)Math.Round(firstN, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); //works
int end = (int)Math.Round(lastN, MidpointRounding.ToZero);          //doesn't work
```

I absolutely need to use `MidpointRounding.ToZero`, there really isn't any alternatives. I would have to rewrite big parts of the code again. Writing my own rounding function just to solve this one problem doesn't sound fun either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MidpointRounding.ToZero`, despite being tacked on to the `MidpointRounding` enum, does not do what you want it to do either. It just truncates the decimal portion of the number, giving you the closest integer not further away from zero:

```
 2.4 ==> 2
 2.5 ==> 2
 2.6 ==> 2
-2.4 ==> -2
-2.5 ==> -2
-2.6 ==> -2
```

So unfortunately it looks like you need a custom rounding method, but it is not difficult:

```
int i = (d < 0) ? (int)Math.Floor(d+0.5) : (int)Math.Ceiling(d-0.5);
```

result:

```
 2.4 ==> 2
 2.5 ==> 2
 2.6 ==> 3
-2.4 ==> -2
-2.5 ==> -2
-2.6 ==> -3
```

Comment: Thanks! I now realized the mistake. I thought it was mirror of what AwayFromZero does, at least it would have made sense. But yeah, it's not. Thanks for a thorough answer!

Comment: What a horrible mistake (introduced in .NET Core 3.0 from 2019) to introduce into an enum type called `MidpointRounding` that already has a member `AwayFromZero` a new member with a similar name `ToZero` that makes the entire operation completely different! Sending `2.6` and `-2.6` to `2` respectively `-2` has nothing to do with the **midpoint** between two destinations. This turns the `Round` method into an already existing method, namely `Math.Truncate`. Entirely misleading! The two other new enum constants turn `Round` into `Floor` and `Ceiling`.

Answer (score 2):

From memory, I believe the directed roundings are fairly new to the framework. I'm not familiar with Unity, but you may want to try changing your target framework if possible.

Alternatively, `Math.Truncate` should provide identical behavior and I would argue clearer intent.

```
int end = (int)Math.Truncate(lastN);
```

Comment: I only need directed rounding for midpoint rounding, i.e. halfs to round down towards zero, but otherwise "normal" rounding rules. 2.1 -> 2 and 2.5 -> 2, but 2.6 -> 3.

Comment: Despite the name, that's not what `MidpointRounding.ToZero` does. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-6.0#system-math-round(system-double-system-midpointrounding)